# Print an array of numbers from the least significant digit to most significant digit?

Tags: c, significant-digits

```
8 | *
7 | *
6 | *
5 | *
4 | * *
3 |* * * * * *
2 |* * * * *** ** * *
1 |* * *** ****** **** * *
+---------------------------
   012345678901234567890123456
             11111111112222222
```

how would you print numbers from the least significant digits to the most significant digits (like the numbers shown on the x-axis)? Thank you

Comment: Can you please clarify how this scatter plot applies to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing from the LSD to the MSD is actually simpler then the other way around.  The reason why is that the remainder/division technique to extract the digits of a number produces the least-significant before the most-significant.

```
if (i == 0)
    output_digit(0)
else
    while (i != 0)
        output_digit(i % base)
        i = i / base
```

This will output digits in the order you want.  For base 10, the number 123 will first output 3, then 2 and finally 1.

Answer (score 2):

Put the number in a temp.

The next digit to print is temp % 10

Divide 10 into temp.

If temp isn't 0, repeat the prior two steps.